# GWT and dependency management

Tags: gwt, maven

Maybe some one can recommend what is the best dependecy management tool when developing GWT applications? I've tried GWT with maven, but that doesn't work very well with GWT unit tests.
Experienced GWT developers, what dependecy management tools do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using maven, as it works well now with tests that extend GWTTestCase, provided you exclude them from surefire plugin as suggested here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/testing.html